# How to display a UITableView, which is placed inside a UIView .xib file?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Loading a custom UIView into the ViewController is simple:

```
if let randomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RandomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? RandomView {

        self.view.addSubview(randomView)

    }
```

This randomView then usually also displays any labels, text fields, etc. which are placed inside of its .xib file. However, if I place a UITableView in its .xib file, it does not get displayed at all.

To add to the confusion: If I create a separate xib file and **only** place a UITableView inside of it, I can load it using `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed` and it gets displayed correctly.

This it not about setting up delegates or data sources I think. The bare empty table itself doesn't get displayed when it's placed inside of randomView's .xib file. Although the other elements like labels, text inputs, etc. do.

The UITableView in the separate .xib file gets loaded and displayed correctly without any delegates or datasources set up.

**The first example doesn't display the table, the second one does.**
[image: description]
[image: description2]

Comment: To get you corret: the tableview is a subview of your `randomView`, but when you add `randomView` as a subview of `self.view`, it does not have the table view anymore as a subview?

Comment: Yes. I've added two screenshots to show the hierarchy of the two examples. Both get loaded into the viewController using the loadNibNamed method.

Comment: How do you access the table view in the first example, in order to setup the data source? Also check the red arrow in the first picture - maybe some autolayout constraints mess up your view?

Comment: So the problem was actually the lack of constraints for the UITableView, which is strange, because none of the other elements in the UIView needed constraints to be displayed. When I had the UITableView in a separate .xib, it also didn't need constraints to be displayed. Thank you for giving the hint!!!

Comment: @r6bQ4xoC79rhJXFw some UI elements have what is called Intrinsic Content size and some don’t. The ones that don’t will not need height and width constraints. The others will need them. Loaded from a xib it would still need with and height but would load based on a best guess most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been caused by missing constraints (see red arrow in the first picture), which prevent the table view to be displayed correctly.